# Calling the function inside helper file

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have inside my helper class inside helpers/common_helper.php

In this page I have following code:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Helper
{
    public static function resFormat($response = array())
    {
```

Now I am trying to call this resFormat function from my controller

I have used following code:

```
public function test()
{
    // GET FORM CONTENTs.
    $paperFormat = $this->Paper_model->getTest();

    $status = 200;
    $response = array('param' => null, 'status' => $status, 'data' => $paperFormat);
    return response()->json(Helper::resFormat($response), $status);

}
```

But for some reason I am getting call to undefined function response()

In my autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('common');
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with your Helper, the error is about the `response()->json` part. Where does that `response()` function come from?

Comment: @rickdenhaan I have added my function

Comment: Ah so it's in a controller. Do you mean `$this->response()` instead of just `response()`?

Comment: Yes I am trying to call helper function from controller. I have tried $this->response too

Comment: And if you do `return $this->response()->json.....` do you still get the "undefined function response()" error?

Comment: Call to undefined method Paper::response()

Comment: Ok it's been a while since I worked with CodeIgniter. Are you sure that's how you output a JSON response? According to a quick Google search, you're supposed to use `$this->output->set_status_header($status)->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode(Helper::resFormat($response)));` unless you've made your own wrapper function to do that for you

Answer (score 0):

Just because declaring your helper file as class, so you can not call helper function directly.

your comm_helper.php should be:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
<?php
    public static function resFormat($response = array())
    {
      // you code 
    }
?>
```